# Is it possible to evaluate a value in an xpath expression?

Tags: xpath

Can I make the value in an XPath query another XPath expression somehow? (Hoping this is possible)

Here's a simplified version of what I'm trying to do: Let's say I have an XML structure like this:

```
<person>
  <info>
    <name>Bob</name>
    <primary_residence>2</primary_residence>
  </info>
  <residences>
    <residence>
      <rid>1</rid>
      <name>New York</name>
    </residence>
    <residence>
      <rid>2</rid>
      <name>London</name>
    </residence>
  </residences>
</person>
```

I'd like to get the name of the "primary residence".  I'd like to do something like:

```
/person/residences/residence[rid=XXX]/name
```

And then, within that, use an "XXX" that looks something like this:

```
/person/info/primary_residence
```

So, all together would look something like:

```
/person/residences/residence[rid=/person/info/primary_residence]/name
```

However, that doesn't seem to work (unless I'm mistaken somehow).

Any ideas?

Comment: "That doesn't seem to work" - it should work fine, what exactly is going wrong? Are you getting no results or too many?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work with any XPath versions :

```
'/person/residences/residence[rid=/person/info/primary_residence]/name'
```

So your expression is valid. What is your programming environment/language ?

---

With XPath 3.0 (or XQuery 1.0 or greater) :

```
let $r := /person/info/primary_residence
return /person/residences/residence[rid=$r]/name
```

Comment: A couple of clarifications. The first solution will work with ANY XPath version; and the parentehse are not needed. The second solution actually requires XPath 3.0 (or XQuery 1.0 or greater).

Comment: Thanks for explanations Michael Kay.

Comment: Why would you expect `text()` to make any difference? The OP's expression should work correctly as-is, comparing the string value of the `rid` element to that of the `primary_residence`

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working at present, either with or without parentheses-- I'm using PHP at the moment. I ... guess I'll have to do additional debugging